# Java ArrayList remove() unexpected result?

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
void reduce() {
    KeyVal reducer1 = new KeyVal();
    for (int i=0; i< m1.size(); i++) {
        reducer1.setKey(m1.get(i).getKey());
        reducer1.setValue(m1.get(i).getValue());

        for (int j=i+1; j < m1.size(); j++) {
              if (m1.get(i).getKey().compareTo(m1.get(j).getKey()) == 0) {
                  m1.remove(j);
                  //System.out.println(i + "-->" + j);
                  reducer1.setValue(reducer1.getValue() + 1);
              }
          }         

        System.out.println(reducer1.getKey());
        System.out.println(reducer1.getValue());
        //r1.add(reducer1);
      }
```

It's basically for counting no. of occurrences of particular entry.
If i am giving input

```
3494702579
3494702579
3494702579
```

I am getting

```
3494702579
2
3494702579
1
```

But I should get

```
3494702579
3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your inner loop, when you remove an element and then increment `j` you in fact might skip an element.

But in general a better way to do what you want is to use HashMap implementation of multi set for example.
Your current solution is `O(n^2)`, while the HashMap one is very close to `O(N)`.

```
void reduce() {
    HashMap<xxx, Integer> reducer1 = new HashMap<xxx, Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i< m1.size(); i++) {
        xxx key = m1.get(i).getKey();

        int count = 0;
        if ( reducer1.containsKey(key) ) count = reducer1.get(key);

        reducer1.put(key, count+1);  
     }
     //print the values
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are removing elements from `m1` while iterating over it. This causes the inner loop to skip some elements. This happens because, after you've removed the `j`-th element, you are still incrementing `j`.

In your example, one of the `3494702579` gets skipped, and is picked up by the second iteration of the outer loop.

The entire logic of your method can be rewritten using a `Map` of keys to counts, and a single pass over the input list.